# Representation of vectors in terms of orthogonal bases

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I recently came across this result:

> Let ${v_1, \cdots, v_k}$ be an orthogonal basis for a subspace $V$ of
>   $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $v$ be any vector in $V$. Then $v = \left(\frac{v \cdot v_1}{  |v_1|^2 }\right)v_1 + · · · + \left(\frac{v \cdot v_k}{  |v_k|^2 }\right)v_k$.

Where does this come from? How can one prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of the unit vectors $${\bf e}_i = \frac{{\bf v}_i}{\| {\bf v}_i \|} $$

The projection of ${\bf v}$ along ${\bf v}_i$ is ${\bf v}\cdot{\bf e}_i$. This is similar to asking to how much of ${\bf v}$ is along ${\bf v}_i$

The vector along ${\bf v}_i$ with magnitude the projection is $ {\bf e}_i ({\bf v}\cdot{\bf e}_i)$ so in total

$$ {\bf v} = \sum_i {\bf e}_i ({\bf v}\cdot{\bf e}_i) = \sum_i \frac{{\bf v}_i}{\| {\bf v}_i \|} \left( \frac{{\bf v}\cdot{\bf v}_i}{\| {\bf v}_i \|} \right) = \sum_i \frac{({\bf v}\cdot{\bf v}_i)}{\| {\bf v}_i \|^2} {\bf v}_i$$

Answer (score 1):

$v$ can be represented as a linear combination of basis vectors.

$v = n_1 v_1 + n_2v_n \cdots n_k v_k$

since the basis is orthogonal

$v_i\cdot v_j = 0$ if $i\ne j$ and $v_i\cdot v_i = \|v_i\|^2$

for each $i, n_i = \frac {v\cdot v_i}{\|v_i\|^2} $

Answer (score 1):

We can express a vector in $V$ as a linear combination of basis vectors. Here the basis chosen is the orthogonal set $\{ v_1, \ldots , v_k\}$. To get the coordinates, you'll need to dot the vector you wish to express against each of the basis vectors, then normalize by dividing by the square of its length.

It can be shown that for any basis $\{ x_1, \ldots , x_n \}$ of $V$ (finite dimension assumed) that we may write

$$ \sum_{j = 1}^n (x \cdot x_j)x $$

where $x \in V$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\{ v_1, \ldots, v_k \}$ is a basis, we can write
$$v = \alpha_1 v_1 + \cdots + \alpha_k v_k$$

Then 
$$v \cdot v_n = (\alpha_1 v_1 + \cdots + \alpha_k v_k) \cdot v_n = 
\alpha_1 (v_1 \cdot v_n) + \cdots + \alpha_k (v_k \cdot v_n)$$

Since it's an orthogonal basis we have $v_m \cdot v_n$ when $m \neq n$, giving
$$v \cdot v_n = \alpha_n (v_n \cdot v_n) = \alpha_n |v_n|^2$$

Solving for $\alpha_n$ and inserting in the expansion of $v$ gives the formula.